# msvc and fold expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, fold-expression, c1001

I'm having trouble compiling this code on Windows.

This code compile correctly on Linux, both with clang and gcc. I'm using msvc 19.29.

Msvc exit with the not so helpful error C1001.

```cpp
struct Object{};

class Storage {
    Object &createObject() {
        qStorrage.push_back(Object{});
        return qStorrage.back();
    }

    template <class... Objs>
    void deleteObject(const Objs&...obj)
    {
        const auto e = std::remove_if(qStorrage.begin(), qStorrage.end(), [&](const auto &i) { return ((i == obj) || ...); });
        qStorrage.erase(e, qStorrage.end());
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to pass multiple reference of `Object` to be deleted, to avoid calling multiple time the same function.

```cpp
Storage stor;

auto a = stor.create();
auto b = stor.create();

stor.delete(a, b);
```

Do you know why MSVC fail to compile this ?

EDIT :

Here is the actual files:

https://github.com/zcorniere/logger-cpp/blob/windows/include/Logger.hpp

https://github.com/zcorniere/logger-cpp/blob/windows/example/example.cpp

build with cmake with parameter BUILD_EXAMPLE turned ON

EDIT2:
Here is msvc error message, sorry I forgot about it

```
message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'bool ProgressBar::operator ==(const ProgressBar &) const' [C:\Users\Zacharie Corniere\Documents\GitHub\logger-cpp\build\example\example.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(1967): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool Logger::deleteProgressBar::<lambda_1>::operator ()<ProgressBar>(const _T1 &) const' being compiled [logger-cpp\build\example\example.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               _T1=ProgressBar
[build]           ]
[build] logger-cpp\include\Logger.hpp(51): message : see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::remove_if<std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<_Ty>>>,Logger::deleteProgressBar::<lambda_1>>(_FwdIt,const _FwdIt,_Pr)' being compiled [logger-cpp\build\example\example.vcxproj]
[build]           with
[build]           [
[build]               _FwdIt=std::_Deque_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<ProgressBar>>>,
[build]               _Ty=ProgressBar,
[build]               _Pr=Logger::deleteProgressBar::<lambda_1>
[build]           ]
```

Comment: When asking question about build errors, always include the *full* and *complete* error output, copy-pasted as text. A proper [mre] would also be helpful.

Comment: Whats compiler error? Are you using same C++ version?

Comment: I updated the questions with the compiler error. I'm using c++20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C1001` is Internal Compiler Error.

It is used to indicate bugs in the compiler itself, the code being compiled is not necessarily wrong.

Report ICE to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ or via *Help > Send Feedback > Report a problem...* from Visual Studio

Try to reduce what exactly produces ICE. This will help both making a good error report and avoiding ICE in your code, as a fix may not be available soon.

---

I've reduced your example:

```
#include <vector>

class ProgressBar
{
public:
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const ProgressBar &) const = default;
};

std::vector<ProgressBar> v;

    template <class... Objs>
    void deleteObject(const Objs&...obj)
    {
        std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const auto &i) { return ((i == obj) || ...); });
    }

int main()
{
    ProgressBar p;
    deleteObject(p);
}
```

See recreated error message: https://godbolt.org/z/dbz34PcTf

I've reported it.

#### Update

According to [developer community feedback item](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Internal-Compiler-Error-with-fold-expres/1522072#T-N1532411), this is internally fixed, so will be available in a preview version in some time.

However, I think it will be in Visual Studio 2022, and it will not be back-ported to Visual Studio 2019.

---

### **Workaround**

In addition to `<=>` operator add `==` operator to `ProgressBar`:

```
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const ProgressBar &) const = default;
    bool operator==(const ProgressBar &) const = default;
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works !
I though the spaceship operator was supposed to replace operator definition like ==, !=, <=, and so on. 
Why is it still necessary here ?

Comment: @dorfen_ because of a compiler bug. Internal Compiler Error indicates that there's a compiler bug

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Sorry. I'm not used to blame the compiler XD

Answer (score 0):

It will not compile, because `delete` is a reserved keyword. Change the 'd' to 'D'.

You also need to add a semicolon at the end of the struct definition.

And you need to declare the qStorrage member (like `std::vector<Object> qStorrage;`).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking correctly, I edited it to fix the misunderstandings.